# How can we send contract transaction with Web3dart package?

Tags: abi, sendtransaction

I'm using [web3dart](https://pub.dev/packages/web3dart) package to send tokens on the Ethereum blockchain. but every time returns error :

```
[log] RPCError: got code -32000 with msg "filter not found".
[log] #0      JsonRPC.call
package:web3dart/json_rpc.dart:62
        <asynchronous suspension>
#1      _FilterEngine._refreshFilters
package:web3dart/…/core/filters.dart:359
        <asynchronous suspension>
```

My code:

```
static Future<String?> sendToken({
    required String selectedAccountSecretKey,
    required String rpcUrl,
    required TokenModel token,
    required String withdrawalAddress,
    required double amountInWei,
    required int chainId,
  }) async {
    try {
      final client = Web3Client(rpcUrl, Client());
      final gasPrice = await client.getGasPrice();
      final credentials = EthPrivateKey.fromHex(selectedAccountSecretKey);
      final sender = await credentials.extractAddress();

      // read the contract abi and tell web3dart where
      // it's deployed (contractAddr)
      final abiCode = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/abi/erc20.abi.json');
      final contractAddress = EthereumAddress.fromHex(token.contractAddress);
      final contract = DeployedContract(
        ContractAbi.fromJson(abiCode, 'ERC20'),
        contractAddress,
      );

      // extracting some functions and events that we'll need later
      final transferEvent = contract.event('Transfer');
      final balanceFunction = contract.function('balanceOf');
      final sendFunction = contract.function('transfer');

      // listen for the Transfer event when it's emitted by the contract above
      final subscription = client
          .events(
            FilterOptions.events(contract: contract, event: transferEvent),
          )
          .take(1)
          .listen((event) {
        final decoded =
            transferEvent.decodeResults(event.topics ?? [], event.data ?? '');

        final from = decoded[0] as EthereumAddress;
        final to = decoded[1] as EthereumAddress;
        final value = decoded[2] as BigInt;

        log.i('decoded response: $decoded');
        log.i('$from sent $value ${token.name} to $to');
      });

      // check our balance in MetaCoins by calling the appropriate function
      final balance = await client.call(
        contract: contract,
        function: balanceFunction,
        params: <dynamic>[sender],
      );
      log.i('We have ${balance.first} ${token.name}');

      final EthereumAddress receiver =
          EthereumAddress.fromHex(withdrawalAddress);

      final txId = await client.sendTransaction(
        credentials,
        //chainId: chainId,
        Transaction.callContract(
          contract: contract,
          function: sendFunction,
          //from: EthereumAddress.fromHex(token.contractAddress),
          //gasPrice: gasPrice,
          parameters: <dynamic>[receiver, BigInt.from(amountInWei)],
        ),
      );

      await subscription.asFuture<dynamic>();
      await subscription.cancel();

      await client.dispose();
      return txId;
    } catch (e, s) {
      log.e('sendToken() error: $e , stack: $s');
      return null;
    }
  }
```